# Printing the first value from more than one vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to print the **first value** from each vector shown below in the main function.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned int vect;

int main() {
    std::vector<vect> p;

    vector<vect> a = { 4,2,3,1 };
    vector<vect> b = { 4,2,3,1 };
    vector<vect> c = { 4,2,3,1 };
    vector<vect> d = { 4,2,3,1 };

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<a.size(); i++)
    cout << a[i];
}
```

Function **first_preference()** from my function.cpp shown below

```
#include "function.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

 person test::first_preference() const {

        const person& first = p.front();
        return first; //current first pref
    }
```

The function is declared in this header class

```
#ifndef FUNCTION_H
#define FUCNTION_H

#include <vector>

typedef unsigned int person;
typedef unsigned int vect;

std::vector<vect> p;


class test {

public:
    person first_preference() const;
};

#endif
```

I want the function **first_preference()** to be called from **main()** where the function should print the first value of each vector, how would I go about this?

Comment: Voting to close as a typo. `&vote::first_preference` is the address of the member function, not a call to it.

Comment: How are functions called?

Comment: `instance.member_function(arguments)` is one way. Make your code into a [mcve] and it'll be easier to help.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I've simplified the question hopefully it will be easier to help? I'm trying to call the function the way you advised but it wasn't working

Comment: You oversimplified. Your simplified code has no `test` object, so a non-static member of `test` cannot be called.

Answer (score 2):

> I want the function `first_preference()` to be called from `main()` where the function should print the first value of each vector

Some issues:

- You have a global `std::vector<vect> p` in your header file (which is not a good idea to begin with) which is shadowed by `std::vector<vect> p` in `main`. What you put in the `p` in `main` will not be accessible from instances of `test`. Those instances only knows about the global `p`.
- You don't `#include "function.h"` in `main.cpp` so you can't create `test` objects in `main`.
- If you `#include "function.h"` in `main.cpp` there's no need to `typedef unsigned int vect;` since you did that in `function.h` already. It's not an error, but confusing and unnecessary.
- The `vector<vect>` instances `a, b, c` and `d` have no connection with `test` or any of the `p`s whatsoever so what you put in those vectors can't possibly be printed by instances of `test` unless you pass them on to `test` somehow.
- You declare vectors of `vect` but `first_preference()` returns a `person` by value. `vect` and `person` happen to be aliases of the same fundamental type, but it seems like there is something wrong with this interface.
- In `main.cpp` you don't instantiate a `test`, you iterate over `a` and `first_preference()` is never called so there's no hope for it to be used.
- [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)